# How to configure turbolinks with a Rails app with asset pipeline feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pushstate, turbolinks

We have a rails 3.2 app, but we are not using the asset pipeline feature, manifest file. 
we minify the scripts and css through YUI compressor.

We want to use turbolinks in our application. I had followed following steps

1. Added the gem to gemfile and bundled it.
2. Next, copied the jquery.turbolinks.js file to javascript folder and included the JS as a last JS in the head.

But it does not seem to work, still getting complete page reload.... any inputs what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

/Gemfile

```
gem 'turbolinks'
```

/app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require turbolinks
```

And restart your server and you're now using turbolinks! [Watch this for more information!](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks?view=asciicast)